# discord.js: syntaxError: Identifier 'client' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot with Node.js and discord.js. and I type node index.js and it said:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({       
       ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'client' has already been declared
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

What to do?

*my index.js:*

```
const { client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client({
        intents: [
                GatewayIntentBIts.Guilds,
                 GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
         ]});
clien.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

*My config.json:*

```
{
      "BOT_TOKEN": "MY BOT TOKEN"
}
```

I am using neovim

My discord.js version is 14.6.0

Comment: You declare `client` on lines 1 and 4. As the error message implies, you can't have two variables with the same name. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you have misspelled `Client`. Use this instead.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
        intents: [
                GatewayIntentBIts.Guilds,
                 GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
         ]});
```

Answer (score -1):

**you need to change the variable name in 4th line from client to another name **

```
const { client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client({ //change here variable name another from client 
    intents: [
            GatewayIntentBIts.Guilds,
             GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
     ]});
clien.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```